# Media query will not affect object

Tags: object, svg, responsive-design

I cant get a media query to affect the following. I need the svg object to change to height:100% @media(max-width:767px)

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/5/image.svg"></object>

    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    object {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I have noticed that after I added `object` tag to my page, something wrong happens with page resolution on the first load, I still didn't find an explanation for that, but for the mean time you may use one of the following tags instead of `object`.

**Using an `<embed>` Tag**

```
 <embed type="image/svg+xml" src="image.svg"/>
```

**Within an `<iframe>`**

```
 <iframe src="image.svg"/>
```

**Using an `<img>` Tag**

```
<img src="image.svg"/>
```

**Using a CSS Background Image**

```
#myelement
{
    background-image: url(image.svg);
}
```

Advantages and disadvantages of loading `SVG` in the previous tags can be found in this great article: [How to Add Scalable Vector Graphics to Your Web Page](http://www.sitepoint.com/add-svg-to-web-page/) by Craig Buckler

happy codding :)